# Il termine "ospite" indica colui che ospita o colui che è ospitato?

Tags: word-usage

[Ospite:](http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ospite) sta ad indicare sia chi ospita che chi è ospitato.

> - Ospite è il termine della lingua italiana per designare tanto chi riceve ospitalità quanto chi la dona. È una parola enantiosemica.

Nell'uso comune del termine, a mio parere, per ospite si intende la persona ospitata e non chi ospita. È corretta questa mia impressione? Quale altro termine è meglio usare per la persona ospitante per evitare malintesi?

Comment: Ospitante é la migliore per definire il padrone di casa, anche se é troppo divertente l'ambiguità di questa parola: )

Answer (score 9):

Stando a quanto dice il sito web dell'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/chi-effettivamente-l-ospite), si può utilizzare "ospitante", oppure, in contesti meno formali, espressioni come "padrone di casa" o "l’amico che mi ospita".

Comment: Interessante, ma il termine ospite come viene comunemente inteso a tuo parere?

Comment: @Josh61 secondo me di solito viene usato per indicare la persona che è ospitata, mentre sento abbastanza frequentemente l'uso di "ospitante" in espressioni come "famiglia ospitante" nel caso in cui si voglia indicare chi ospita

Comment: @Josh61 Personalmente, prima di leggere la tua domanda non mi ero mai posto il problema se *ospite* potesse essere usato al posto di *ospitante*, in quanto l'associazione *ospite* <-> *ospitato*, almeno per l'uso che io ne faccio e che sento comunemente, è molto forte. È vero che ci sono delle situazioni peculiari dove si usa con l'altro significato, come nel linguaggio scientifico, ma lì si è quasi in un altra lingua con un gergo a parte.

Answer (score 5):

Per indicare il “padrone di casa”, soprattutto nel caso di cene e simili, esiste anche il termine più ricercato “[anfitrione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/anfitrione/)”, in ricordo dell'omonimo personaggio leggendario che concesse ospitalità a Giove e Mercurio.

Comment: Esatto, ad esempio riporto l'Enciclopedia Treccani sull'argomento: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/anfitrione

Answer (score 4):

Direi che in generale, la regola per distinguere tra i due significati è:

> Quando *ospite* è preceduto da un sostantivo, si intende "ospitante" : famiglia ospite, organismo ospite.
>
> Altrimenti, significa "ospitato": partecipare come ospite, essere ospite di qualcuno.

Aggiungerei una nota: nello scritto, conviene usare appropriatamente "ospitante" e "ospitato" proprio per evitare queste ambiguità.

Answer (score 3):

Come parziale risposta alla prima domanda, l'uso di "ospite" come sinonimo di "ospitato" dipende fortemente dal contesto.

Come controesempio, in biologia si usa frequentemente l'espressione "organismo ospite" per indicare un organismo al cui interno si sviluppa un altro organismo simbionte.

Comment: Interessante l'esempio dell'uso scientifico.

Answer (score 3):

Da un noto romanzo:

> La risoluzione di Lodovico veniva molto a proposito per i suoi ospiti, i quali, per cagion sua, erano in un bell’intrigo.
>
> A quel suono risposer subito di dentro le urla e le strida di mastini e di cagnolini; e, pochi momenti dopo, giunse borbottando un vecchio servitore; ma, veduto il padre, gli fece un grand’inchino, acquietò le bestie, con le mani e con la voce, introdusse l'ospite in un angusto cortile, e richiuse la porta.
>
> Poiché la seccatura non si poteva scansare, si risolvette di affrontarla subito, e di liberarsene; s’alzò da tavola, e seco tutta la rubiconda brigata, senza interrompere il chiasso. Chiesta poi licenza agli ospiti, s’avvicinò, in atto contegnoso, al frate, che s'era subito alzato con gli altri; gli disse «eccomi a’ suoi comandi»; e lo condusse in un’altra sala.
>
> Del resto, tra [Agnese e Lucia] e i loro ospiti era nata subito una grand’amicizia; e dove nascerebbe, se non tra beneficati e benefattori, quando gli uni e gli altri son buona gente?
>
> Allo spuntar del giorno, eran tutt’e due in cucina; Renzo in arnese da viaggio, con la sua cintura nascosta sotto il farsetto, e il coltellaccio nel taschino de’ calzoni: il fagottino, per andar più lesto, lo lasciò in deposito presso all’ospite.

La parola *ospite* appare molte altre volte nell’accezione di *persona ospitata*, come in due dei casi precedenti. Ma in tre di quei passi (e in altri non riportati) l’accezione è di *persona ospitante*.

Se il contesto non rende chiaro altrimenti, *ospite* è, in genere, la persona ospitata. Il significato originale del latino *hospes* è *chi ospita*, ma già nel latino classico si trova anche con il significato di *persona ospitata*. Quindi l'ambiguità è molto antica.

Comment: La citazione e' molto interessante, e sull'ambiguità dell'uso mi sembra ci siano pareri concordi nelle risposte riportate finora. La mia impressione è' che nel linguaggio contemporaneo 'ospite' sia usato quasi esclusivamente   nel senso di 'ospitato' (forse per evitare malintesi), mentre 'ospite' nel senso di 'ospitante' sia più raro o , come notato, appartenga ad un gergo tipo quello scientifico.

Comment: @Josh61 Dipende da chi parla; a me capita di usare *ospite* nel senso originale (cioè *chi ospita*). Ma è vero, più comune è il senso di *chi è ospitato*.